# CREATE EVENT Conflict

Tags: mysql, sql

I am an aspiring DBA, trying to hone my skills. I am running MySQL 5.5 on Ubuntu Server 12.04 for a SysLog server my company would like to go live. The only hitch in the giddyup is instead of using the LogAnalyzer's purge function, I would like to create my own SQL to place the log files in a separate table for an extended period of time each month and then purge them completely after six months.

After multiple tests, I know my queries work and I think the problem lies in the CREATE EVENT portion. But the events still do not fire and nothing has been moved.

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE EVENT SystemLogPurge

ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2014-7-29 15:55:00'

DO BEGIN

INSERT INTO PastSystemEvents SELECT * FROM SystemEvents WHERE ReceivedAt < 
DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL -1 MONTH);

DELETE FROM SystemEvents WHERE ReceivedAt < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL -1 MONTH);

DELETE FROM PastSystemEvents WHERE ReceivedAt < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL -6 MONTH);

END;

;;
```

Is there something I am missing? Or can it even be done?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in your server variables that event_scheduler = ON. 
It may seems obvious but sometimes we get stuck and forget to check simple things.
You can try this :

SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

or add/change this variable in your my.cnf file